# Parsing through a JSON file with Python 2.x

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to parse through a text file containing a number of Facebook chat fragments. The fragments are stored as below:-

```
{"t":"msg","c":"p_100002239013747","s":14,"ms":[{"msg":{"text":"2what is the best restauran
t in hong kong? ","time":1303115825598,"clientTime":1303115824391,"msgID":"1862585188"},"from":10000
2239013747,"to":635527479,"from_name":"David Robinson","from_first_name":"David","from_gender":1,"to_name":"Jason Yeung","to_first_name":"Jason","to_gender":2,"type":"msg"}]}
```

I've tried a number of ways to parse / open the JSON file but to no avail. Here is what I've tried thusfar:-

```
import json

data = []
with open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\facebookchat.txt", 'r') as json_string:
    for line in json_string:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

*error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Amy/Desktop/facebookparser.py", line 6, in <module>
    data.append(json.loads(line))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 91 (char 91)
```

and also:

```
import json

with open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\facebookchat.txt", 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

... but I get exactly the same error as above.

Any suggestions? I've searched previous posts on here and tried the alternative solutions but to no avail. I'm aware I need to treat it as a dictionary file with for example, 'time' being a key and '1303115825598' being the respective time value but if I can't even process the json file into memory, there's no way I can parse it.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your data contains newlines where JSON would not allow these. You'll have to stitch the lines back together again:

```
data = []
with open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\facebookchat.txt", 'r') as json_string:
    partial = ''
    for line in json_string:
        partial += line.rstrip('\n')
        try:
            data.append(json.loads(partial))
            partial = ''
        except ValueError:
            continue  # Not yet a complete JSON value
```

The code collects lines into `partial`, but minus the newline, and tries to decode the JSON. If that succeeds, `partial` is set to the empty string again to process the next entry. If it fails, we loop to the next line to append, until there *is* a complete JSON value to decode.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I'd copied the JSON extract from the internet hence the formatting error. I've made the file into one continual string and  it is read correctly now. Thanks again